# Simple quiz with different levels DIVs

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that I want the game to be in. When I put the code for the easy quiz in and click the "Finish" button it works and I get my notification that tells me the score. When I add the other quiz codes for Medium and Hard the Finish button doesn't work at all, even if I have the DIVs for the other 2 Hidden. What I wanted to do is have the other difficulties hidden until a button is clicked and it'll show up. Right now I haven't given the buttons any functions since I want to figure out the issue with the "Finish" button.

```
    <!-- Border for the game -->
<form id="divbox3" name="quiz">
  <div class="game-button" style="width:50%">
    <button style="width:33%">Easy</button>
    <button style="width:33%">Medium</button>
    <button style="width:33%">Hard</button>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- Easy Quiz code -->
  <p class="questions">Most moles have an extra thumb to dig with. <b> True or False? </b></p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q1">

  <p class="questions">What is the smallest country in the world? <b> Tuvalu - Vatican City - Monaco </b></p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q2">

  <p class="questions">What is the biggest atom on the periodic table? <b> Uranium - Radon - Radium - Lead </b></p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q3">

  <p class="questions">Who is the richest man in the world? <b> Bill Gates - Jeff Bezos - Elon Musk </b></p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q4">

  <input id="button" type="button" value="Finished!" onclick="check();">
</form>


<!-- Border for the game -->
<form id="divbox3med" name="quiz" hidden>

  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- Medium Quiz code -->
  <p class="questions">What type of animal is Bambi</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q1">

  <p class="questions">Name a US state beginning with K.</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q2">

  <p class="questions">Who wrote the Harry Potter series?</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q3">

  <p class="questions">Who wrote 'The Scarlet Letter'?</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q4">

  <input id="button" type="button" value="Finished!" onclick="check();">
</form>

<!-- Border for the game -->
<form id="divbox3hard" name="quiz" hidden>

  <br>
  <br>

  <!-- Hard Quiz code -->
  <p class="questions">What chemical element is diamond made of?</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q1">

  <p class="questions">What game features the terms love, deuce, match and volley?</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q2">

  <p class="questions">Which planet did Superman come from?</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q3">

  <p class="questions">How many syllables make up a haiku?</p>
  <input id="textbox" type="text" name="q4">

  <input id="button" type="button" value="Finished!" onclick="check();">
</form>

<div id="scoresheet">
  <p id="number_correct"></p>
  <p id="message"></p>
</div>
```

This is the Js for the easy quiz, the other ones are similar.

```
function check(){

    var q1 = document.quiz.q1.value;
    var q2 = document.quiz.q2.value;
    var q3 = document.quiz.q3.value;
    var q4 = document.quiz.q4.value;
    var correct = 0;


    if (q1 == "True") {
        correct++;
}
    if (q2 == "Vatican City") {
        correct++;
}   
    if (q3 == "Francium") {
        correct++;
    }
    if (q4 == "Jeff Bezos") {
        correct++;
}

    var messages = ["Amazing!", "Getting there...", "Ouch :/"];
    var score;

    if (correct == 0) {
        score = 2;
    }

    if (correct > 0 && correct < 4) {
        score = 1;
    }

    if (correct == 4) {
        score = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById("scoresheet").style.visibility = "visible";

    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[score];
    document.getElementById("number_correct").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " correct.";
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w1kgqyce/

This is how I have it currently. The other 2 DIVs are not visible and hidden. Without the code for the other difficulties other than EASY the "FINISH" button work, but as soon as I implement the rest of it, it doesn't work. For some reason I can't show what I want to on Fiddle. I'm sorry for the bad explanation, I'm just really confused rn :s 
Thank you

Comment: id mus be unique

Answer (score 0):

Use unique IDs on the questions.

Get rid of the duplicate ID on your input classes - that is bad syntax & against the rules of how IDs work (ID needs to be unique ; it will work if it's not ... but all of the assumptions of working with the DOM are broken if you use non-unique IDs.)   Turn the ID of your input classes into a class, and give each one unique IDs.

Also - need to see the JavaScript to make a definitive answer.

But - I've seen this a million times where IDs that break the rules for IDs cause forms to break.   That's the only reason I'm even answering without seeing the JS!

=============

Ok , looking at your fiddle it's a bit more clear.

1. Buttons need an event listener so when you click them, it toggles
   the visibility on the correct quiz, and toggles all others as
   invisible.
2. Each quiz should have its own event that triggers your check()
3. Update the check() to have a parameter to differentiate your quizes
4. Lastly - differentiate your answers.   I'm thinking a better way to do this would be to use an object + have your answers in the object by difficulty:

   answers = {
   "easy":{"q1":"Answer1",
           "q2":"Answer2",
           "q3":"Answer3",
           "q4":"Answer4"
           },

   "medium": {"q1":"Answer1",
           "q2":"Answer2",
           "q3":"Answer3",
           "q4":"Answer4"
           },

   "hard": {"q1":"Answer1",
           "q2":"Answer2",
           "q3":"Answer3",
           "q4":"Answer4"
           }
   }

( *Sorry about the formatting on the JSON.  Having trouble to get it to display correctly.* )

Then to check your answers if you had them set up like this:

```
if (easy) { 
    check = answers.easy; 
}
else if (medium) { 
    check = answers.medium; 
} 
else { 
    check = answers.hard; 
}
```

Then when you get to the point to check your answers ... you check against the set of answers you pulled from the object:

```
if (answer1 == check.q1) {
     // Do what you need done.
}
```